# Call .net DLL's from C# code

Tags: .net, dll, tfs

I want to call some .net DLLs from csharp code using tfs. The problem is that i cannot add the reference of these DLL's directly into my solution, as i need a independent solution for this. This is because the DLL's to be called changes frequently and new DLL's are also added in it. So how can i use TFS to call them through code.

Comment: Why can you not use references? We have an Assemblies folder in our TFS and we add the reference to the DLL from that folder. Upon each checkin of the solution for that DLL, we take care that we checkin the new DLL into the Assemblies folder aswell.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure where TFS would come in, but what you are looking for is System.Reflection.  There is an article that will lay it out for you at

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32828/Using-Reflection-to-load-unreferenced-assemblies-a

Answer (score 0):

Are these other DLLs created from VS projects? If I were doing this, I'd add the projects to a single solution, then add references to dependent projects instead of to the output DLLs directly.

Comment: yes they are created in VS only. But i need to call them without adding any reference

Comment: I was using batch files to achieve this but batch file execution is not controlled, so looking for a better approach

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you would use not referenced dlls, but for me it sounds a bit like you need to use reflection. Another approach I have used in my project was the AddIn option of .Net:
Official Microsoft explanation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384200(v=vs.90).aspx
An example from Codeproject, which was very helpful for me: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25866/AddIn-Enabled-Applications

Might be helpful to know more about the issue why you would not reference the dlls.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, this is more or less what you need:

```
private void LoadUpdatedAssembly()
{
    var versionControlServer = _tfs.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
    var tempFilePath = Path.GetTempFileName();
    if (File.Exists(tempFilePath))
    {
        File.SetAttributes(tempFilePath, FileAttributes.Normal);
        File.Delete(tempFilePath);
    }
    versionControlServer.DownloadFile(@"$/<TeamProject>/<SourceControlFilePath>.dll", tempFilePath);
    var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(tempFilePath);
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(assembly.GetName());
}
```

And then you can access it most easily with "Dynamics":

```
static void UseDynamicallyLoadedAssembly()
{
    dynamic dynamicExampleClass  = new ClassInAssembly();
    dynamicExampleClass.MethodOfTheClassInTheAssembly (10, 4);
}
```

As always with dynamics (or reflection) You take full responsibility for what you write as all errors will be reveled in run-time.